# UIImageView doesn't resize itself to the UIImage it holds

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a `UIImageView` with Auto-layout to the container margins. I set a `UIImage` to it in the ViewController. If I use `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` then the image is centred in the middle of the screen as I wanted and everything looks great, but when I give the `UIImageView` a background color, I can see it still spreads all the way to the container margins, and doesn't get the image's proportions and dimensions. This is my code:

```
UIImage *passedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:self.photoTitle];
CGRect imageBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, passedImage.size.width, passedImage.size.height);
[self.imageView setImage:passedImage];
self.imageView.bounds = imageBounds;
self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

I have tried everything to fix it and looked everywhere for answers, please help me, you are my only hope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of pinning the image view's edges to the container margins, pin its center X and center Y to the container's center X and center Y.

This gives the same visual result — the image is centered — but leaves the image view free to resize itself according to its contents.

Comment: I wish I could upload a screenshot to make it clear, but I can't, so I'll try to explain: when pinning to the margins, I get the image in the center of the screen, with the width all the way to the margins, so it fits the screen. When I pin the view's center to the X and Y, the view's top is at the container margin, the bottom gets all the way to the bottom of the screen (maybe extends beyond it?), left at margin, right extends to the right of the screen, and the image's bounds are the same as the view's (extend beyond the screen).

Comment: Well it sounds to me like that's a problem with your _image_. It's too big and it has a bunch of white space on all sides of itself.

Comment: Yes, it is big (1122 x 1084), but no white space. What can I do about it?

Comment: What do you _want_ do to about it? I no longer know what you want to do. You said you wanted the image view to resize itself to the image, and I told you how to do that. And it worked perfectly! But it turns out that the image is too big, so when that happens, the image and the image view are too big. _What do you want to do_? Do you even know?

Comment: Sorry if I was misunderstood at first, I want the image and the image view to fit in the screen. It's a PNG with a hole in it, behind it I have a camera so the user can take a photo with his face inside the hole. I then merge it to a single photo the user can share. The camera UIView frame gets it's size from the image view frame, that is why I need the image view to get the size of the image, and both of them to fit the screen.

Comment: "I want the image and the image view to fit in the screen" But that is what you had to start with. You complained that "when I give the UIImageView a background color, I can see it still spreads all the way to the container margin". But now it turns out that that is what you wanted! So I still don't see what the problem is.

Comment: " I need the image view to get the size of the image, and both of them to fit the screen" But we already established that that is impossible, because _the image is much bigger than the screen_! Please think about what you want and ask a question about that. Stop going around in circles.

Comment: I didn't want the image view background color to spread to the margins like you say. I wanted it to be exactly behind the boundaries of the image. what I meant was that I need the image view to fit the screen the same way the image fits the screen when I use UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit, even though the real size is apparently bigger. I appreciate your efforts to help me so much but the problem still hasn't resolved. Please help me, I'm desperate.

Comment: But I still don't know what you want. I don't see any evidence that _you_ know what you want. How big do you want the image to be? If you know, then make it that size (and now the image view can be the same size).

Comment: I need the actual size of the image to stay big, so that if the user shares it, it stays in it's original size. but on the device screen I want the image to look smaller (to fit completely on screen), I already got that by using UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit. The reason I also need the UIImageView to fit completely on screen is that I have a UIView behind it that gets the UIImageView's width and height. This UIView displays the front camera so what the user see on screen is the PNG image and his own face through a hole in the PNG. He can then take a picture of that and share it.

Comment: "I need the actual size of the image to stay big, so that if the user shares it, it stays in it's original size. but on the device screen I want the image to look smaller" Okay, good spec. Then when the time comes to draw the image on the screen, redraw it, scaling it down so that it is the actual size that is right for the screen. That is a good idea in any case, because drawing an image that is larger than the drawing wastes memory! The original image, meanwhile, stays on disk waiting to be shared (at its original size).

Comment: Using a smaller image and setting the UIImageView's constraints to center X and Y solved my problem! thanks a lot! (It got me encountered in another problem though, but I bothered you enough).

Answer (score -1):

UIImageView does not resize itself according to image size it renders. If you need to size it accordingly, you need to do it yourself. Matt's answer is reasonable, but you still need to update your image view size at some point. I'd suggest doing it in `layoutSubviews` or `updateConstraints` method of your view or in view controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: "UIImageView does not resize itself according to image size it renders" Yes, under auto layout that is _exactly_ what it does, if other constraints do not prevent it.